# function find(x,p,'first') in R

Tags: r, matlab

Good Morning,
I am trying to replace the function find (by `Matlab`) in R, in particular I want to replace the following functions:
`I=find(x,p,'first'), L=find(x,q,'last') , A=I(x) and B=L(x)` where `x` is a vector,`p` and `q` are the number of elements I'm interested in.

I don't understand how I can replace the command: 'extract the position of first(last) `p(or q)` elements of vector `x`'.

Comment: Check out `?head` and `?tail`

Comment: `?which` might be what you're looking for. Also, it could just be indexing.  See `?"["`. It would be easier to tell if we had example input and output.

Comment: Is `x` a logical vector?

Comment: x<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80) is a vector of number and suppose that p<-3 and q<-5 I want to write a function in R that returns me the following vectors x<-c(10,20,30) and y<-c(40,50,60,70,80) thanks for your advice =D

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
p <- 2
q <- 2

I = head(which(x),p)
L = tail(which(x),q)
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with `A=I(x)` since `I` and `x` will have fewer elements than `x`

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dan, I am not sure what you want: the first p elements and last q elements or element p and element q.  For the latter:

```
require(stringi)
x <- c("dog", "cat", "FALSE", "TRUE", "BLUE")
p <- 2
q <- 3
unlist(stri_extract_words(str = x))[p]
unlist(stri_extract_words(str = x))[q]
```

For the first p or last q, another line of code would be needed to count the elements and set the range.